# How to get an offline player by UUID?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

How to get an offline player by UUID? I can get an online player by UUID by iterating through all online players and return when an UUID matches, but I don't know how to do this for offline players.

Comment: You should have done some research, or at least tried before you asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta build of CraftBukkit (1.7.9-R0.1) has the method you need in `org.bukkit.Server` interface:

```java
/**
 * Gets the player by the given UUID, regardless if they are offline or
 * online.
 * <p>
 * This will return an object even if the player does not exist. To this
 * method, all players will exist.
 *
 * @param id the UUID of the player to retrieve
 * @return an offline player
 */
public OfflinePlayer getOfflinePlayer(UUID id);
```

[JavaDoc](http://jd.bukkit.org/beta/apidocs/org/bukkit/Server.html#getOfflinePlayer%28java.util.UUID%29)

Related issue: [BUKKIT-5501](https://bukkit.atlassian.net/browse/BUKKIT-5501)
Related commit: [4bc86be4](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/commit/4bc86be459a7ce310f523ca03e2908c1d29956f4)