# Replacing UUID of player to player's name

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to send a message to the player with his saved friends. These friends are saved in a .yml file, but only the UUIDS of each individual player.

I am then trying to replace the UUID or convert it to the players name when the message is displayed (if that made sense)

CODE:

```
p.sendMessage("§7▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄§aFriend System - page 1 of 1§7▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄");

          int i = 1;
          int length = cfg.getList(p.getUniqueId() + ".Friends").size();
          if (length != 0)
          {
            while (i <= length)
            {
              String uuid = (String)cfg.getList(p.getUniqueId() + ".Friends").get(i - 1);
              ProxiedPlayer p2 = ProxyServer.getInstance().getPlayer(UUID.fromString(uuid));
              if (p2 != null)
              {
                TextComponent prefix = new TextComponent(Main.prefix);

                TextComponent join = new TextComponent("§a§lONLINE");



                prefix.addExtra("§9" + p2.getName());
                prefix.addExtra(" ");
                prefix.addExtra(join);

                p.sendMessage(prefix);
              }
              else
              {
                String name = getNamebyUUID(uuid);
                if (name != null)
                {
                  p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§9" + name + " §c§lOFFLINE");
                  Main.names.put(uuid, name);

                }
                else if (Main.names.containsKey(uuid))
                {
                  p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§9" + (String)Main.names.get(uuid) + " §8[§c§lOFFLINE§8]");
                }
                else
                {
                  p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cThis is not a valid player!");
                }
              }
              i++;
            }
          }
          else
          {
            p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYou don't have any friends.");
          }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Bukkit.getPlayer(UUID).getDisplayName();

Answer (score 1):

Related Question: [Get Offline Player by UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788976/how-to-get-an-offline-player-by-uuid?rq=1)

---

If the **Player is online**:

---

```
String playerUUID;
Bukkit.getPlayer(playerUUID).getDisplayName();
```

---

If the **Player is offline**:

---

Not trully possible. The Player can change names at any time, and Bukkit can't keep that information and keep updating all the player's name whenever they change.
You can either use the online-player-only method above, or store the player's name together with the uuid.

**@UPDATE**

As stated by the user *Pokechu22*, Bukkit does save the **last** name the user used before logging out. It can be retrieved this way:

```
OfflinePlayer off = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(String uuid);
String lastKnownName = off.getName();
```

But be very careful! It might not be the up-to-date name of the player.

---

Comment: Bukkit stores the player's last known name.  You can't get the _current_ name while they're offline if it changes (unless you manually request it from the mojang API), but   You can use `OfflinePlayer.getName` to get the last known name.  (Just, you can't use `getDisplayName`).

Comment: That's true! Updated my answer. Thanks!